# How to plot IP address frequency distribution chart on Excel or Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have one column of data:

```
IP Address
1.2.1.2
1.2.1.2
1.3.4.1
1.3.4.1
1.3.4.1
1.3.4.1
1.3.4.1
1.10.0.5
1.10.0.5
1.10.0.5
2.1.2.1
2.1.2.1
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
12.1.2.3
...
254.1.2.3
254.1.2.3
254.1.2.3
```

I need to present the above in Frequency against IP Address Chart. How can I do it in Excel or Calc? Preferably the IP addresses can be collapsed into subnets for visualization purpose.

Comment: Just use a pivot-chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the candidates in column **B** and in **C1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$21,B1)
```

and copy down...........then plot **B** vs **C**

[image]

Comment: List of candidates from list of IP's: Select column A, copy to column B, reselect column B, find 'Remove duplicates' in the menus.

Comment: Using a pivot table would also provide you with a unique list of candidates, and the count of each, which could then be graphed.